# become or have become

Tags: present-perfect

My role model is Roald Dahl.   Reading his books,  i found myself fascinated by his interesting stories and creative characters. I especially like the messages and lessons in his books. I learned that we should always believe in our abilities. As a result,  I **became** more confident and hopeful about my future.

Here,  because the resulative confidence has a relevance to present time, **became** can be replaced with **have become?**

Two have different meanings in this context or interchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will for the most part be interchangeable, though there is a small difference if they are used in alternate sentences.

"I became" refers to a change in the past, but doesn't say anything about what happened after.

"I have become" refers to a change that has happened, ending with a result in the present.

So in a sentence like "I became more confident after I met her, but then I learned the truth. now I just can't believe in myself anymore". It would not be possible to use "I have become", because it would clash with the later statement, that I'm no longer confident.

Answer (score 0):

> My role model is Roald Dahl. Reading his books, **I find** myself fascinated by his interesting stories and creative characters. I especially like the messages and lessons in his books. I **have** learned that we should always believe in our abilities. As a result, I **have become** more confident and hopeful about my future.

From what I can tell, this paragraph is about your fondness for Roald Dahl in the *present*. It follows that the final sentence should be in the present perfect, otherwise it won't make any logical sense. So **became** is incorrect.